# PHP does not work INSERT INTO method

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am trying to insert into customer table in eshop_db
When I run it, it does not have any error, but it did not store in mysql.
What it is problem in my code?
I don't understand really.
Please give some answer. Thanks.

--registerForm.php--

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
    <p>User ID: <input type="text" name="userId" size="30"/>*</p>
    <p>Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="30"/>*  </p>
    <p>Retype Password: <input type="password" name="repassword" size="30"/>*</p>
    <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" size="30"/>*</p>
    <p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" size="30"/>*</p>
    <p>Your Address (*):</p>
    <p><textarea name="address" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea></p>
    <p>Phone: <input type="text" name="phone" size="20"/>*</p>
    <p>E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" size="21"/>*</p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Create Account"/></p>
</form>
```

--register.php--

```
<?php
require "sql_connection.php";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if($_POST["password"]==$_POST["repassword"])
    {
        mysql_query("insert into customer (userId, password, firstName, lastName, address, phone, email) 
        values ('$_POST[userId]','$_POST[password]','$_POST[firstName]','$_POST[lastName]','$_POST[addres]]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[email]')")
        or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
?>
```

--sql_connection.php--

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_pass = "mypass";
$db_name = "eshop_db";

@mysql_connect("$db_host", "$db_username", "$db_pass", "$db_name") or die("connection is fail.");
@mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("database does not exsist.");
echo "Successfully connected!!";
?>
```

Comment: [SQL Injection](http://il.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: Never insert in your db the values you recieve by the $_POST variable ! Never !

Comment: can you check if you are going into the first `if` condition by printing something when it enters that?

Comment: Besides the obvious SQL injection vulnerability, try to print the SQL before executing it, so you see what you're actually executing.

Comment: Make sure it is actually firing an insert query i.e. your password and repassword are really equal. Some logging might help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php

require "sql_connection.php";

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST["password"] == $_POST["repassword"]) {

  mysql_query(
'INSERT INTO `customer` (`userId`, `password`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `address`, `phone`, `email`) 
  VALUES ('.$_POST['userId'].', '.$_POST['password'].', '.$_POST['firstName'].', '.$_POST['lastName'].', '.$_POST['address'].', '.$_POST['phone'].', '.$_POST['email'].')'
  ) or die(mysql_error());

}
```

Finally, filter and validate your incoming data.

Answer (score 2):

Typo, correct this part here:

```
 '$_POST[addres]]' // wrong
 '$_POST[address]' // right
```

Comment: '...'.$_POST['address'].'...' - quote the indexes

Comment: Why downvote? He had a 'addres' instead of 'address' and also an additional bracket?

Comment: Style issues and vulnerabilities aside, this seems to be the reason the query fails.

Comment: Further note: the OP and this answer are in fact using unquoted keys correctly. [This is not only legal, but necessary in a double quoted string.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) If you use quoted keys you must use concatenation, which provides no perceivable difference in performance and consumes more memory, though this is negligible. Therefore, this is an issue of personal style, not of code correctness.

Answer (score 0):

Well, besides the obviously bad idea to directly use the values in the POST array, your indexes need to be quoted. So, $_POST['address'], etc. Also, array values need to be escaped with curly-braces if you're trying to do string injection.